# Count instances of specific item w/Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm working on pulling a list from sharepoint using the SPServices. The data loads fine, however I am trying to count the number of instances where a specific word/option is used.
The data is something like:

```
"Name" : "George" , "Payment" : "CC"
"Name" : "Phillip", "Payment" : "CC"
"Name" : "Frances", "Payment" : "PO"
"Name" : "George",  "Payment" : "PO"
"Name" : "George",  "Payment" : "CC"
```

What I am trying to do is to count the number of instances where CC vs PO occurs for George. 
I've tried a couple things the only thing that kinda works - though it only displays '1' is:

```
for ( var i = 0; i< entries; i++) {
    if (Name == "George") {
       if (Payment == "PO") {
           ++POs;
       }
       if (Payment == "CC") {
           ++VCCs;
       }
    }
 }
```

This however returns:
George 1
George 1
George 1

EDIT:
Per request here is the display:

```
$('myTable").append(
 "<tr>" + "<td>" + Name + "</td>" +
 "<td>" + Pos + "</td>" +
 "<td>" + CCs + "</td>" +
 "</tr>"
 )
```

Comment: Offhand, your loop pseudocode looks sound, but you need to post the actual code you're running to see what you're doing. Also, your pseudocode is checking for a payment type of "VCC" whereas your data value is "CC".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to describe how your data is actually delivered and stored in an object. Its possible that the method you use to store the data is the source of your trouble. Also I suggest that you update your question with code you are actually using.

Here is a guess at what might work for you:

```
var data = [{"Name" : "George", "Payment" : "CC"},
            {"Name" : "Phillip", "Payment" : "CC"},
            {"Name" : "Frances", "Payment" : "PO"},
            {"Name" : "George",  "Payment" : "PO"},
            {"Name" : "George",  "Payment" : "CC"}];

function countPaymentTypes(data) {

    var userData = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
        // get name
        var currentName = data[i].Name;

        // create user object if one does not exist yet
        if(userData[currentName]==undefined) {
            userData[currentName] = { POs: 0, CCs: 0 };
        }

        // add payment type to count variables
        if (data[i].Payment === "PO") {
            userData[currentName].POs+=1;
        }
        else if (data[i].Payment === "CC") {
            userData[currentName].CCs+=1;
        }

     }
    return userData;
}    

var userPaymentCounts = countPaymentTypes(data);

console.log(userPaymentCounts.George.POs); // 1
console.log(userPaymentCounts.George.CCs); // 2
console.log(userPaymentCounts.Frances.POs); // 1
console.log(userPaymentCounts.Frances.CCs); // 0
```

Then with the user counts you might do something like:

```
for (var userName in userPaymentCounts) {
    $('myTable').append(
     "<tr>" + "<td>" + userName + "</td>" +
     "<td>" + userPaymentCounts[userName].POs + "</td>" +
     "<td>" + userPaymentCounts[userName].CCs + "</td>" +
     "</tr>"
     );
}
```

Comment: The code being used is pulling the data from sharepoint. As I can get the data to pull and display just fine I left that out, as of right now it displays line after line of data - each line telling me a person, and if its a CC or PO. I want to count and return the number of PO vs CC.

Comment: The above you suggested works better then what I had. What I had only returned undefined. Yours however returns the amount of counts, not the instances. Pretty much returns POs == data.length

Comment: I don't think that your end goal is well stated. I have updated the code to match my understanding of your needs.

Comment: That more or less works, had to change a couple things, but it works pretty well, thank you